# Node.js package script that runs every time a file is changed

Tags: node.js, filesystems, node-modules, watch

I'm developing a node.js package that generates some boilerplate code for me.

I was able to create this package and if I run every module individual it works fine and generates the code as expected.

My idea now is to import this package in another project and have it generate the code.

I have no idea to how to achieve this or even if it's possible.

The perfect solution would be that every time a file changed in a set of folders it would run the package and generate the files but if this isn't possible it would be ok as well to expose or command to manually generate this files.

I have created a script to run the generator script but it only works on the package itself and not when I import it in another project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [fs.watch()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) function.  It invokes a callback when a file (or directory) changes.

```js
import { watch } from 'fs';

function watchHandler (eventType, filename) {
  console.log(`event type is: ${eventType}`)  /* 'change' or 'rename' */
  if (filename) {
    console.log(`filename provided: ${filename}`)
  } else {
    console.log('filename not provided');
  }
}

const options = { persistent: true }

const watcher = fs.watch('the/path/you/want', options, watchHandler)
...
watcher.close()
```

You can use this from within your nodejs app to invoke watchHandler() for each file involved in your code generation problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't mean that I would have to implement this function in every project where I import the package that generates the code? The initial idea is just to import the package that generates the code to another project and voila it should generate the code automatically or at least expose a command to do the code generation. Thanks